# API using a Function Call in Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets

So I have this google sheets API, and I am grabbing data from it and running a KS test. However, I only want to run the KS test on a number. But, the string consists of words as well. For instance,

2020-09-15 00:05:13,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.51058,
2020-09-15 00:05:43,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.75889,
2020-09-15 00:06:09,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.23385,
2020-09-15 00:06:33,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.23191,
2020-09-15 00:06:58,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.94495,
2020-09-15 00:07:23,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.16024,
If I have this as a string, How would I run a KS test on just the last numbers of each line. For instsnace, I only want to run the KS test on -.51,-.75,-1.23,-1.23,-.94,-1.16

Here is a screenshot of my Google sheet

[image]

Here is some of my code:

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import  ServiceAccountCredentials
import re


np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
def estimate_cdf (col,bins=10,):
    print (col)
    # 'col'
    # 'bins'

    hist, edges = np.histogram(col)
    csum = np.cumsum(hist)



    return csum/csum[-1], edges
    print (csum)



scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("sheet1").sheet1  # Opens the spreadhseet

data = sheet.get_all_records()


row = sheet.row_values(3)  # Grab a specific row






number_regex = r'^-?\d+\.?\d*$'





col = sheet.col_values(3)  # Get a specific column print (col)

col2= sheet.col_values(4)
dolphin= estimate_cdf(adjusted := [float(i) for i in col if re.match(i, number_regex)], len(adjusted))



print(col)
print(col2)




shtest =stats.shapiro(col)
print(shtest)




#thelight= sheet.update_cell(5,6,col)
#print(thelight)

k2test =stats.ks_2samp(col, col2, alternative='two-sided', mode='auto')
print(k2test)
```

And here is some of my error message:

```
temperature,64.79599999999999,65.03830769230765', '2020-09-25 11:38:51,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.85,65.01338461538458', '2020-09-25 11:39:16,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.994,64.99538461538458', '2020-09-25 11:39:42,metsense,htu21d,temperature,65.066,64.98015384615381', '2020-09-25 11:40:06,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.94,64.95799999999996', '2020-09-25 11:40:31,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.976,64.93861538461535', '2020-09-25 11:40:57,metsense,htu21d,temperature,65.066,64.93307692307688', '2020-09-25 11:41:22,metsense,htu21d,temperature,65.048,64.93584615384611', '2020-09-25 11:41:48,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.994,64.92753846153843', '2020-09-25 11:42:12,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.976,64.93169230769227', '2020-09-25 11:42:37,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.94,64.9441538461538', '2020-09-25 11:43:03,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.994,64.95523076923072', '2020-09-25 11:43:28,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.9']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/james/PycharmProjectsfreshproj/shapiro wilks.py", line 60, in
    shtest =stats.shapiro(col)
  File "C:\Users\james\PycharmProjectsfreshproj\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\morestats.py", line 1676, in shapiro
    a, w, pw, ifault = statlib.swilk(y, a[:N//2], init)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ',,,,,'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

python

Comment: and yes, I will post twice, because I have waited a week and still not gotten a response to this question. So please answer the question

Comment: You can edit the old question to bump it in the queue